# What is the best way to get latitude and longitude from GPS in Android?

Tags: android, gps, latitude-longitude, android-permissions

Just simple as that.I dont want to find new coordinates every 10 minutes or meters.I just want to click a button and get my coordinates for this exact moment/place where i am.Every tutorial i've seen its old.New android versions require permissions to use GPS or Network.I am trying to implement those but nothing seems to work.
Any solutions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I feel like this is a "I don't really understand the examples." kind of question.  Remember that as the GPS sensor receives updates, it receives them at different accuracies.  If you happy to accept a very inaccurate reading then sure...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I just want to click a button and get my coordinates for this exact moment/place where i am

That's not possible in general. The device may not *know* the user's "coordinates for this exact moment/place". You are welcome to call `getLastKnownLocation()` on `LocationManager`, or perform equivalent sorts of lookups with Play Services' fused location provider, but they may return `null`. Usually, to find out where the user is, you request location updates, then react when you get a location fix.

> Every tutorial i've seen its old

[These sample apps](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Location) (for the fused location provider) and [this sample app](http:///home/mmurphy/stuff/CommonsWare/books/Omnibus/samples/Internet/Weather) (for `LocationManager`), from [my book](https://commonsware.com/Android), should be up to date.

> New android versions require permissions to use GPS or Network

All Android versions require permissions to determine the user's location, for blindingly obvious privacy reasons. This has been the case since before Android 1.0, and it should remain the case for the foreseeable future.

> I am trying to implement those but nothing seems to work

Then ask a fresh Stack Overflow question, where you provide [a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating your problems.

Comment: The LocationManager sample app does not open.
Is there a simple way to ask for permitions?I hit alt enter then the studio gives me an if statment and then it says in the comments to overide functions which i cannot overide for some weird reason.Ive seen people on the internet writing and then everything just pops up.I guess this isnt the case or i have to implement something (i dont know what)

Comment: @ParryHotter: "The LocationManager sample app does not open" -- I do not know what you mean by "does not open". "Is there a simple way to ask for permitions?" -- I do not know what you mean by this either. When your app needs permissions, the primary thing is to have the `<uses-permission>` elements in the manifest in the proper spot. On Android 6.0 the story gets more complicated, but that app has a `targetSdkVersion` less than 23, so it should behave on 6.0 the way it behaves on prior versions.

Comment: Yea that was my point from the begining.At the previous versions you just go and add permissions to the manifest file and you are done.From 23 you have to always make a popup window and ask for permission again -.-

Comment: @ParryHotter: If you are not ready to take on the Android 6.0 runtime permissions, set your `targetSdkVersion` to 22 or lower. Your app will behave as all apps did in the past, where the user is prompted for all permissions at installation time. While my `LocationManager` sample is written that way, the fused location provider samples *do* have a `targetSdkVersion` of 23 and handle the runtime permissions... because that does get complicated, particularly when interacting with Play Services.

Comment: @CommonsWare sir, can you help me please with [this quetion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33930061/4044787)