# Android Gradle Include SQL File in Source Folder

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Sorry to ask about "obviously" not best practice for putting sql file in source folder, but its the requirement of my company.
So, I have a sql file that i had to put it on source folder, but after build the gradle, my apk file doesn't contain the sql file.
My project tree :
[image]

My apk file contains :
[image]

And my `build.gradle` file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ods.loadsheet"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("keystore.properties")
            storePassword "****"
            keyAlias "****"
            keyPassword "****"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/' }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
    compile "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.0.0"
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.3'
    compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.quentin7b:android-location-tracker:3.0'
    compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.9.1'
}
```

Comment: SQL file should b kept in asset folder

Comment: @bond007 yes i know, but i need it to put on src file. do you have solutions for that?

Comment: SRC folder only supports .java and .aidl files. I don't think it can be done

Comment: @bond007 i have other application (use ionic framework) that dont use gradle for build. it has same structure as shown above, and my sql file is included in my apk file. so maybe i need to edit my gradle, so it can include sql file too